# Activate SQL-Logging via Spring Boot and Hibernate via Environment variables (casing problem)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, naming-conventions

I want to log all SQL-Statements in SpringBoot 2.7.0. In https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot#2-via-loggers it is done via the following properties:

```yaml
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql: true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: DEBUG
```

This works fine as long as I use the `.yml`-File. But I have to set it via Environment Variables in OpenShift.

Unfornenatly the Docs https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0#environment-variables don't say much about the writing of

- `format_sql` (underscore in property)
- `hibernate.SQL` (all uppercase)
- `sql.BasicBinder` (CamelCase in property)

I've tried the following ones, but none of them work:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_HIBERNATE_SQL=DEBUG
LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_HIBERNATE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SQL_BASICBINDER=TRACE
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL=true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use name : **logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL**

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the properties are: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE and spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true